# install pygraphviz on anaconda error

Tags: python, pygraphviz

I try to install pygraphviz on Anaconda. I have done everything I found:

```
- install graphviz.
- install mingw.
- change values in the setup.py for pygraphviz as below:
   include_dirs = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/include/graphviz'
   library_dirs = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/lib'
-  run python setup.py build -c mingw32 install.
```

After step 4, I got the following error:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'pygraphviz._graphviz' extension
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DGVDLL "-IC:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/include/graphviz" -IC:\Users\garre_000\Anaconda3\
include -IC:\Users\garre_000\Anaconda3\include -c pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\pygraphviz\graphviz
_wrap.o
pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:2954:29: fatal error: graphviz/cgraph.h: No such file or directory
 #include "graphviz/cgraph.h"
                             ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

Can anyone give me some advice ?

Comment: Is your include path correct?  Perhaps it should be include_dirs = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/include'?

Comment: I figured it out though. I switched from python 3.3 to python 2.7. It worked fine. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just faced the same problem. The include path is incorrect. Use

```
include_dirs = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/include'
```

instead. Otherwise you get

```
'C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/include/graphviz/graphviz/cgraph.h'
```